# API for storing binary blobs

Tags: serialization, semantics

I'm doing some moderately low-level programming of an embedded device that has some NVRAM we plan to use for retaining values between runs of a program. We'd like to abstract the operations into an API over a driver or talking to a daemon.  This is lower-level than the serialization semantics I've seen here and there.  Basically we want a process or function to be able to reserve some space (with some name or other identifier), store a value (arbitrary byte sequence) in that reserved space, retrieve the value later, and surrender the reservation if it no longer needs to use it.  This feels a lot like `malloc`, `write`, `read`, and `free`.  I'm tempted to implement `nvAlloc()` (or something) and so on. Or am I missing something obvious?  Maybe security: another process getting a handle and accessing or corrupting the value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems http://pramfs.sourceforge.net/ and normal file system access are the right answer.